# Why is $e^{-f(z)} = 1-z$, when $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why does the following hold?
    $$e^{-f(z)} = 1-z$$
where $f(z)$ is defined as:
    $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$$
Clearly, $f'(z)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty z^n =\frac{1}{1-z}$ by the known sum of geometric series, so the question is similar to:
    $$e^{f(z)} = f'(z)$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With $g(z) = (1-z)e^{f(z)}$ it follows that $g'(z) = 0$ and $g(0)=1$ so yes, we have $e^{-f(z)} = 1-z$ for $|z| < 1$ where the series converge.

Comment: $-\log(1 - z) = \sum z^n/n$ near $0$, as your argument implies. (Your summation of $\sum_{n\geq 2} z^n$ is off, though.) You can show also show that $\exp -f(z) = 1 - z$ by considering the corresponding formal series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $g(z)=(1-z)e^{f(z)}$, then,
  $$g'(z)=0$$
So it follows that $g(z)=c$ (constant).
The constant $c$ is found to be one by evaluating $g(0)$.

Comment: I think that minus sign in the exponential should go.